# Rewrite everything exclude index.html

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got following structure of site:

index.html

/assets/subpage.html

/assets/secondpage.html

And I wrote following rules in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets
RewriteRule (.*) /assets/$1 [QSA,L]
```

I want to delete .html from files (first rule) and I want to skip /assets (third and forth rule). However I would like to exclude .index.html from 3 i 4 rules. Right now when I type:

www.example.com it redirects me to www.example.com/assets/.html ( i would like this one to redirect me to www.example.com)
and when I type www.example.com/subpage it redirects me to: www.example.com/assets/subpage.html

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.html$|assets/) [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) assets/$1 [L]
```

- Added a `RewriteCond` in first rule check for existence of `.html` file
- Used `.+` to make sure we don't match landing page

Comment: But my index.html is in folder above, my htaccess also, how to fix this?
I mean I have:
index.html
.htaccess
/assets

and inside assets I have 2 subpages
And when I apply your rule I get info:
The requested URL /assets/index.html was not found on this server.

so should I place ../ somewhere to force htaccess to go up in directory?

Comment: Try my updated code. Make sure to replace all of your .htaccess code with this one.